# Could these facts lead to a conviction for manslaughter or other crimes?

Tags: criminal-law, manslaughter, suicide

Here are the facts:

1. A person (A), an adolescent, posts a poll on his Instagram story. It asks ‘Should I kill myself?’ The options are ‘yes’ and ‘no’.
2. Forty people vote on the poll. Only four people vote ‘yes’. Half of those four voters know A personally, while the other half do not.
3. After A sees the results of the poll (i.e. only how many people voted ‘yes’ and how many voted ‘no’), he commits suicide.

In your jurisdiction, would any or all of the four people who voted ‘yes’ on this poll be convicted of manslaughter or any other crime(s)?

Comment: As always, "where" matters. This is not a subject upon which the law is uniform and "in  your jurisdiction" really isn't specific enough.

Answer (score 1):

### Manslaughter: no, Other crimes: maybe

[new-south-wales](/questions/tagged/new-south-wales)

Section [31C](http://www.austlii.edu.au/cgi-bin/viewdoc/au/legis/nsw/consol_act/ca190082/s31c.html) of the *Crimes Act* 1900 creates the awkwardly named crime of "AIDING ETC SUICIDE":

> (2) Where--
>
> (a) a person incites or counsels another person to commit suicide, and
>
> (b) that other person commits, or attempts to commit, suicide as a consequence of that incitement or counsel,
>
> the firstmentioned person shall be liable to imprisonment for 5 years.

The prosecution would need to prove beyond reasonable doubt that that voting yes on the poll amounted to either "incitement or council" - a difficult but not impossible task.